# IndexError: list index out of range while using multi-valued command line arguments

Tags: python, index-error, mfcc

I have two codes: one for preprocessing an audio file and another for generating the MFCC. The MFCC code has 3 multi-valued command line arguments (frame length, frame step and fft length). I have defined mfcc as:

```
def mfcc(audio,sample_rate,pre_emp):      
    for fl in args['frame_length']:
        for fs in args['frame_step']:
            for fft in args['fft_length']:
                audio = np.pad(audio,(Paddinggg(fl,fs,sample_rate),0),mode='reflect')
                audio = audio.astype('float32')
  #Normalization
                audio = tf.keras.utils.normalize(audio)
  #Preemphasis
                audio = Preemphasis(audio,pre_emp)
                
                stfts = tf.signal.stft(audio,fl,fs,fft,window_fn=tf.signal.hann_window)
                spectrograms = tf.abs(stfts)
                
                num_spectrogram_bins = stfts.shape[-1]
                lower_edge_hertz, upper_edge_hertz, num_mel_bins = 0.0, sample_rate/2.0, 32
                linear_to_mel_weight_matrix = tf.signal.linear_to_mel_weight_matrix(num_mel_bins, num_spectrogram_bins, sample_rate, lower_edge_hertz,upper_edge_hertz)
                mel_spectrograms = tf.tensordot(spectrograms, linear_to_mel_weight_matrix, 1)
                mel_spectrograms.set_shape(spectrograms.shape[:-1].concatenate(linear_to_mel_weight_matrix.shape[-1:]))
  
  # Compute a stabilized log to get log-magnitude mel-scale spectrograms.
                log_mel_spectrograms = tf.math.log(mel_spectrograms + 1e-6)
  
                return log_mel_spectrograms
```

The code for preprocessing uses the above function as shown below:

```
  X = []
  Y = []
  preemphasis = 0.985
  print("Feature Extraction Started")
  for i,class_list in enumerate(data_list): #datalist = all files, class list = folder name in datalist, sample = path to the audio file in that particular class list
      for j,samples in enumerate(class_list):    #samples are of the form classes_name/audio file
        if(samples.endswith('.wav')):
          sample_rate,audio = wavfile.read(os.path.join(C["dire"],samples))
          if(audio.size<sample_rate):
            audio = np.pad(audio,(sample_rate-audio.size,0),mode="constant")

          coeff = mfccwithpaddingandcmd.mfcc(audio,sample_rate,preemphasis) # 0.985 = preemphasis

          X.append(coeff)
          #print(X)
          if(samples.split('/')[0] in classes):
            Y.append(samples.split('/')[0])
          elif(samples.split('/')[0]=='_background_noise_'):
            Y.append('silence')
          
# #X= coefficient array and Y = name of the class


  A = np.zeros((len(X),X[0].shape[0],X[0][0].shape[0]),dtype='object')
  for i in range(0,len(X)):
    A[i] = np.array(X[i])      #Converting list X into array A
    # print(A.shape)
```

Now when I am trying to define A, I am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Aarti\.spyder-py3\preprocessingwithpaddingandcmd.py", line 151, in <module>
    pp()

  File "C:\Users\Aarti\.spyder-py3\preprocessingwithpaddingandcmd.py", line 104, in pp
    A = np.zeros((len(X),X[0].shape[0],X[0][0].shape[0]),dtype='object')

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have doubts that it is because of multi-valued command line arguments. Am I correct? How can I solve this problem where I have multi-valued command line arguments and so multiple values of A?

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Did you do debug prints of `X` and `Y`, so you can see what shape they have?  In order for your code to work, `X` needs to be a three-dimensional array.

Comment: @ewong: The following is the full traceback error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Aarti\.spyder-py3\preprocessingwithpaddingandcmd.py", line 151, in <module>
    pp()

  File "C:\Users\Aarti\.spyder-py3\preprocessingwithpaddingandcmd.py", line 104, in pp
    A = np.zeros((len(X),X[0].shape[0],X[0][0].shape[0]),dtype='object')

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please include that traceback in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried but it directly goes to the IndexError without even printing the lengths. This is what I did before defining A:

if(samples.split('/')[0] in classes):
            Y.append(samples.split('/')[0])
          elif(samples.split('/')[0]=='_background_noise_'):
            Y.append('silence')
          print(len(X))
          print(len(Y))

Comment: What do you get if you print “X[0][0].shape[0]” right before you define A?

Comment: It **can't** just skip the `print`.  You're sure you had the indentation lined up with the `A = np.zeros` line?

Comment: error message shows you which line makes problem - so first you could use `print()`, `print(len(...))`, `print(type(...))` **before this line** to check what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: I tired indenting the code properly and it solved my issue. Thank you for all the help.